# Unterschiede zwischen „Scheiße“ und „Scheiß“

Tags: difference

Diese Frage bezieht sich auf die richtige Anwendung der Begriffen *die Scheiße* und *der Scheiß*.

Warum klingen etwa

- *lass die Scheiße!* (anstelle *lass den Scheiß!*)
- *aber dieses Mal mach keine Scheiße!* (anstelle *mach keinen Scheiß*)
- *jemandem aus dem Scheiß ziehen bzw. helfen* (anstelle *aus der Scheiße*)

ein bisschen falsch, wenn im Prinzip beide Wörter die gleiche <sup>1</sup>  Bedeutung haben?

Sachlicher, wie kann man wissen, wann das eine Nomen benutzt werden soll, wann das andere?

<sup>1</sup>  EDIT: Anscheinend haben die Nomen nur ähnliche Herkunft – die Bedeutung sei aber unterschiedlich. Ich lasse aber meinen Fehler hier.

Comment: An sich gute Frage, aber SO falsch klingen die nicht. Eignetlich garnicht falsch. Ich verwende alles... ähm, dass heißt ich würde es verwenden, wäre es nicht so vulgär ;)

Comment: Ersteres ist eine Substanz, letzteres ein Attribut.

Comment: Ich würde sagen "Scheiß", maskulin, ist Bairisch für Blödsinn, dummes Zeug. Ich glaube nicht, dass ein Bayer sagen würde "Mach keine Scheiße". "Scheiß" ist also eine Regionalvariante.

Comment: @rogermue: Quellen für diese Behauptung?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Die Scheiße

Die Scheiße ist zunächst mal das Produkt, das man beim Scheißen hervorbringt, also jene braune Masse, die vorher im Darm eines Menschen oder Tieres war, und die man durch den After ausscheidet.

Scheiße gilt als Inbegriff alles Schmutzigen. Sie stinkt, sieht nicht besonders ästhetisch aus und macht unansehnliche Flecken. Daher hat man schon immer alles mit Scheiße verglichen und mit ihr gleichgesetzt, was man als wertlos und schmutzig empfand oder was man abwerten wollte, und so ist es wenig verwunderlich, dass das Wort für Scheiße in den meisten Sprachen als Schimpfwort verwendet wird. Das geht so weit, dass man als Bezeichnung für das Ausscheidungsprodukt, also für das, was damit ursprünglich bezeichnet wurde, neue Begriffe erfinden muss, wenn man sachlich darüber sprechen will (z. B. beim Arzt).

Das Substantiv »Scheiße« stammt vom Verb »scheißen« ab, dieses wiederum von »scheiden« (im Sinn von »ausscheiden«), welches wiederum vermutlich indogermanische Wurzeln hat (»skei« = trennen, schneiden). Eine Herkunft vom griechischen »schizo« (gesprochen »skizo«) (»spalten«, »teilen«) wird ebenfalls diskutiert.

---

### Der Scheiß

Dieses Wort stammt natürlich von »die Scheiße« ab, dürfte sich davon aber erst vor relativ kurzer Zeit abgespalten haben. Ich vermute, dass die Abspaltung in den Siebziger- oder Achtzigerjahren des 20. Jahrhunderts stattfand und dass »der Scheiß« Teil der Jugendsprache war. In meiner Kindheit (geboren 1965) kannte ich jedenfalls ausschließlich die weibliche Form.

Die männliche Variante hat sich gänzlich vom biologischen Ausscheidungsprodukt losgelöst und findet ausschließlich als Schimpfwort Verwendung, ohne irgendeinen Bezug zu festen, flüssigen oder gasförmigen Stoffwechselprodukten.

Und weil diese Verbindung zu der weichen braunen Masse fehlt, kann man auch niemanden aus dem Scheiß ziehen, weil eben auch niemand im Scheiß stecken kann. Wenn man wo drinsteckt, dann ist das noch immer die Scheiße, und aus der kann man auch jemanden bei Bedarf rausziehen.

Bei den beiden anderen Beispielen halte ich persönlich sowohl die männliche als auch die weibliche Form für möglich:

> Lass die Scheiße!
>   Lass den Scheiß!

bzw.

> Mach keine Scheiße!
>   Mach keinen Scheiß!

Welcher der beiden Formen jeweils der Vorzug gegeben wird, wird vermutlich von eigenen Vorlieben oder dem jeweiligen Nutzungsgrad des sozialen Umfelds abhängen.

Answer (score 5):

> 1. lass die Scheiße! (anstelle lass den Scheiß!)
> 2. aber dieses Mal mach keine Scheiße! (anstelle mach keinen Scheiß)
> 3. jemandem aus dem Scheiß ziehen bzw. helfen (anstelle aus der Scheiße)

-

> Scheiß --> Synonym: Unfug

Ein Umstand der als unsauber empfunden wird. Bzw. wo die Person Abfall produziert.

> Scheiße --> Synonyme: Kacke oder Dreck

Ein Objekt, das einen bei Kontakt dreckig macht.

**Regel:**

Ersetze die Worte Scheiß oder Scheiße jeweils mit Unfug oder Kacke bzw. Dreck.

> 1 Lass die Kacke / den Dreck. (in Ruhe?)

--> Aber (Unter)lass den Unfug.

> 2 Aber dieses Mal mach keinen Dreck.

--> Aber dieses mal mach keinen Unfug. 
(Besser treib keinen Unfug.)

> 3 Jemandem aus dem Unfug ziehen.

--> Aber jemanden aus dem Dreck ziehen.

Comment: "Die Scheiße"=fest. "Der Scheiß"=gasförmig

Comment: @Phira... ist das ernst gemeint?

Comment: nein, das ist bayrisch.